# Is partial replication of couch db doc with attachment possible?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase

We use couchDB (and CouchBase on mobile/tablet). Some of the couch documents have attachments.
Is it safe to assume that when the document (which has attachment) is replicated to tablet, the attachment is also completely available? Is it possible that only couch document is available with partial/no attachment (when network is slow or if disconnected mid-way)?

I query for the doc (on the tablet) and assume that attachment is replicated.

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: We are facing problem processing attachment stream for newly replicated docs. We assumed that replication is kind of 'atomic' - both doc and attachment or nothing. Is there anything documented about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication is done by reading the changes feed of the source database and applying each change. When you create a document with an attachment, you usually do so by first creating the document and then adding the attachment, so two change events are created. However, you can do both in one request by specifying the attachment directly in the json document using base64 encoding. My guess is that this would create only one change event.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look at it from change event perspective. I will try that.